# Invite friend using new Facebook iOS SDK ( Invitable vs taggable friends )

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am struggling with new Facebook SDK changes, in my app i want to have functionality to send app invite to all my Facebook friends, before this it was possible using graph API and FQL but now using new Facebook SDK i am only getting friends list which are already using my app.

i have gone through Facebook documentation as well as different blogs and following is my findings:

**Invitable friends :**

*- In this case we will receive all friends but this is strictly for app which will falls under category game. and this invite will appear in game section of user facebook wall.*

**Taggable friends :**

*- In this case also we received temporary token for all friends, but this can be used just to post on user wall or user stories and we can't use this for sending invite as we don't have user actual userid.*

is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 6):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

If your App is NOT a game on Facebook Canvas, don´t use Requests and `invitable_friends`. Just use the Send and Message Dialogs (depending on your platform) as you can read in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. can you please provide me more info that how to get friend list for this purpose as list i am getting using above two api are sending temporary token.

Comment: you don´t need any friend list. just use the send or message dialogs and the user can choose his friends in there.

Comment: even if your app is a canvas game, you can just use the tokens you get by using invitable_friends. what else would you need?

Comment: To add to @luschn's answer, please do not try to send invites to all friends, that will be considered spam.